# Django - Rotating File Handler stuck when file is equal to maxBytes

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with the RotatingFileHander with Django.

The problem is that when the file is up to the maxBytes size, it will not create a new file, and give an error message when you are trying to do logger.info("any message"):

The strange part is:

1. Nobody is sharing loggers, views would have their own logger, tasks from celery have their own loggers.
2. Loggers are only initiated once at the top of the file (chartLogger = getLogger...) Different functions in the same file will be using the same name

   ```
   Logged from file views.py, line 1561
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 77, in emit
       self.doRollover()
     File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover
       os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
   WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
   ```

Inside my settings.py, I have:

```
    LOGGING = {
            'version': 1,
            'disable_existing_loggers': True,
            'formatters' : {
                'standard' : {
                    'format' : '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
                },
            },
            'handlers': {
                'celery.webapp' : {
                    'level' : 'ERROR',
                    'class' : 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
                },
                'celery' : {
                    'level' : 'INFO',
                    'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                    'filename' : 'logs/celery.log',
                    'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                    'backupCount' : 10,
                    'formatter' : 'standard',
                },
                'views.error' : {
                    'level' : 'ERROR',
                    'class' : 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
                },
                'views' : {
                    'level' : 'INFO',
                    'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                    'filename' : 'logs/views.log',
                    'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                    'backupCount' : 10,
                    'formatter' : 'standard',
                },
            },

            'loggers': {
                'celery.webapp' : {
                    'level' : 'ERROR',
                    'handlers' : ['celery.webapp'],
                    'propogate' : True,
                },
                'celery.webapp.task' : {
                    'level' : 'INFO',
                    'handlers' : ['celery'],
                    'propogate' : True,
                },
                'views.logger' : {
                    'level' : 'ERROR',
                    'handlers' : ['views.error'],
                    'propogate' : True,
                },
                'views.logger.login' : {
                    'level' : 'INFO',
                    'handlers' : ['views'],
                    'propogate' : True,
                },
                'views.logger.register' : {
                    'level' : 'INFO',
                    'handlers' : ['views'],
                    'propogate' : True,
                },
                'views.logger.chartConfigure' : {
                    'level' : 'INFO',
                    'handlers' : ['views'],
                    'propogate' : True,
                },
                'views.logger.sendEmail' : {
                    'level' : 'INFO',
                    'handlers' : ['views'],
                    'propogate' : True,
                },
            },
    }
```

I have tried to change different file sizes, but it gets stuck at maxBytes.

Althought it said that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by some other processes. All the logging is fine before it hits maxBytes.

EDIT:

I've split the logging between celery and django.

```
LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'formatters' : {
            'standard' : {
                'format' : '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
            },
        },
        'handlers': {
            'celery.webapp' : {
                'level' : 'ERROR',
                'class' : 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            },
            'celery' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/celery.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
            'celery_chartConfigure' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/celery_chartConfigure.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
            'celery_register' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/celery_register.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
            'views.error' : {
                'level' : 'ERROR',
                'class' : 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            },
            'views' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/views.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
            'views_login' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/views_login.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
            'views_sendEmail' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/views_sendEmail.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
            'views_register' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/views_register.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
            'views_chartConfigure' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'class' : 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename' : 'logs/views_chartConfigure.log',
                'maxBytes' : 1024*1024*10, # 10MB
                'backupCount' : 10,
                'formatter' : 'standard',
            },
        },

        'loggers': {
            'celery.webapp' : {
                'level' : 'ERROR',
                'handlers' : ['celery.webapp'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'celery.webapp.task' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['celery'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'celery.webapp.chartConfigure' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['celery_chartConfigure'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'celery.webapp.register' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['celery_register'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'views.logger' : {
                'level' : 'ERROR',
                'handlers' : ['views.error'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'views.logger.login' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['views_login'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'views.logger.register' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['views_register'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'views.logger.chartConfigure' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['views_chartConfigure'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
            'views.logger.sendEmail' : {
                'level' : 'INFO',
                'handlers' : ['views_sendEmail'],
                'propogate' : True,
            },
        },
}
```

However, it is still having problems doing doRollOver.

Wouldn't splitting logs between celery and Django solve it issue? Because it isn't several processes accessing the log, but only Django or Celery.

EDIT 2:

I'm also doing Ajax calls. Would this somehow spawn another process that might be interfere with logging?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess you are facing the problem described in this post: [Django logging with RotatingFileHandler error](http://azaleasays.com/2014/05/01/django-logging-with-rotatingfilehandler-error/)

That is, when running Django development server, actually there are two processes running.

> by default, two processes of Django servers are running. One is the
>   actual server, while the other is to detect changes in the code and
>   reload the server. Therefore, settings.py is imported twice, and
>   consequently the two processes are accessing the log file at the same
>   time.

As advised there, try

```
python manage.py runserver --noreload
```

Answer (score 15):

As describe in other answers `python manage.py runserver --noreload` will work. But here's another solution that still works with code reload.

Add this at the end of your settings.py

```
if DEBUG and os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true':
    LOGGING = {}
```

`python manage.py runserver` starts a python process that launches your server in a child python process. Each time the parent detects a change it recreates a new child. The problem is that the log rotation by the child process fails because the parent still has a handle on that file. This solution tells the parent that there are no log file.

Comment: Thanks, shall try this next time

Comment: This works like a charm thank you.  It was a PITA to have to switch to `--noreload` or remove my log rotation when developing on my desktop.

Comment: Nice. See [autoreload.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0/django/utils/autoreload.py#L226) to understand why this works.

Comment: @djvg - I was initially confused because the name of the variable being set is `DJANGO_AUTORELOAD_ENV`. But then I realized that’s actually a string variable that’s equal to `'RUN_MAIN'`.

Comment: Beware: using this approach, `settings.LOGGING` will also be empty when running the Django shell (`manage.py shell`), because `'RUN_MAIN'` is not defined there. The same goes for PyCharm's Django console. An additional test for `'shell' not in sys.argv`, or `'--mode=client' not in sys.argv`, could help here. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748934).